# Running _remap() once

Tags: php, codeigniter

When a user is logged in, I would like them to be able to visit `http://website.com/user` and be taken to `http://website.com/1/johndoe`, where `1` is their user ID, and `johndoe` is their user name.

I'm trying to use `_remap()` to catch all attempts at `http://website.com/user/`, so even incomplete URIs like `http://website.com/user/1` or `http://website.com/user/1/joh` are redirected to `http://website.com/user/1/johndoe`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    function index($uID, $user) {
        echo $uID;
        echo $user;
    }

    function _remap() {
        $uID = 3;
        $user = 'johndoe';
        //redirect('user/'.$uID.'/'.$user); // Updates URI, but redirect loop
        //$this->index($uID, $user); Works, but doesn't update the URI
    }

}
```

I could of course detect the method first, and do something like this:

```
function _remap($method = '') {
    if ($method != 'view') {
        $uID = 3;
        $user = 'johndoe';
        redirect('user/view/'.$uID.'/'.$user);
    }
}

function view($uID, $user) {
    echo $uID;
    echo $user;
}
```

But then I think the URI would look like `http://website.com/user/view/1/johndoe`, and I'd rather `view` was excluded. How should I go about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use is:

```
$route['user/(:num)/:any'] = 'user/view/$1';
$route['user/(:num)'] = 'user/view/$1';
```

Really, the username should only be for SEO purposes and in which case, should not be passed to the action. You will of course be able to access the username from the UserID when you look up the user anyway, so I feel it's redundant.

The above will match

```
/user/1/jdoe
/user/1
```

but will only pass `1` to your `user/view` action.

Edit: With your comment in mind:

```
$route['user/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'user/view/$1/$2';
$route['user/(:num)'] = 'user/view/$1';

function view($UserID, $UserName = null) {
    // Load the model and get the user.
    $this->model->load('user_model');
    $User = $this->user_model->GetByUserID($UserID);
    // If the user does not exist, 404!
    if (empty($User)) {
        show_404();
        return;
    }
    // If the UserName does not exist, or is wrong,
    // redirect to the correct page.
    if($UserName === null || strtolower($User->UserName) != strtolower($UserName)) {
        redirect("user/$UserID/{$User->UserName}");
        return;
    }
}
```

The above will accept the username as the parameter, however if it is not supplied or if it is not correct, it will redirect to the correct url and continue.

Hopefully this solves your problem?

Comment: It's redundant, yes, but it's a matter of vanity. Stack Overflow behaves exactly this way. My profile can be found at `http://stackoverflow.com/users/704015/jezen-thomas`. If I malform the username segment, SO automatically corrects it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `_remap()` method - it will always be called, so redirecting to *user/anything* will still call `_remap()` on the next request, so not only do you need to catch the router method *and* its parameters - you must do it if you want to use `_remap()` in a way that makes any sense:

```
public function _remap($method, $args)
{
    if ($method === 'user' && (empty($args) OR ! ctype_digit($args[0])))
    {
        // determine and handle the user ID and name here
    }
    else
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $args));
    }
}
```